# C#  и Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

Подскажите как работать в C# с Mysql. Что подключать, как подключатся к mysql и как искать в бд.

Answer (score 4):

Официальный [провайдер](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).
Ну и соответственно [документация](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-net.html).

Answer (score 2):

насколько я помню, в ADO.NET есть провайдер данных MySQL.

Comment: А можете ссылку скинуть на примеры

Answer (score 1):

Сперва вам надо загрузить mysql-connector-net-6.9.9 для Visual Studio!
После установки mysql-connector-net-6.9.9, открываете VS создаёти новое приложение или открыв старое, в образователе решений находите ссылки и кликаете правой кнопкой мишы, открывшемся меню выбераете добавить ссылку и в менеджере ссылок выбераете MySql.Data!

После вводите следуюшие строки:

```
using MySql.Data.MySql;
```

и

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {

    string connStr = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=434506_visitmain;UID=root;PASSWORD=mypw";
    MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
    MySqlCommand myComm = myConn.CreateCommand();
    MySqlDataReader Reader;
    myComm.CommandText = "SELECT name_col FROM colprof_col WHERE shortname_col='Quincy'";
    myConn.Open();
    Reader = myComm.ExecuteReader();
    while (Reader.Read())
    {
      MessageBox.Show(Reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
}
```

}
}

Comment: Как по мне, проще в Nuget набрать "MySql" и нажать Install.

Comment: Да это намног проше я забыл упамянуть, спасибо за поправку!